# Php check multiple array key values for true or false

Tags: php

I have an array something like below.

[image]

I need to check all possibilities of action_keys and value for true or false

Have tried like below, but need to know if there is any optimized way to do the same in PHP

```
if( ($userInfoArray[0]['action_key'] =='loggedin' && $userInfoArray[0]['value']==1) && ($userInfoArray[1]['action_key'] =='optin' && $userInfoArray[1]['value']==1)    ){
        echo "LOGGEDIN and OPTIN---"; 
    }
    else if( ($userInfoArray[0]['action_key'] =='loggedin' && $userInfoArray[0]['value']==0) && ($userInfoArray[1]['action_key'] =='optin' && $userInfoArray[1]['value']==0)   ){
        echo "LOGOUT and OPTOUT---"; 
    }
    else if( ($userInfoArray[0]['action_key'] =='loggedin' && $userInfoArray[0]['value']==1) && ($userInfoArray[1]['action_key'] =='optin' && $userInfoArray[1]['value']==0)  ){
        echo "LOGGEDIN and Not Opted---"; 
    }
    else if( ($userInfoArray[0]['action_key'] =='loggedin' && $userInfoArray[0]['value']==0) && ($userInfoArray[1]['action_key'] =='optin' && $userInfoArray[1]['value']==1) ){
        echo "LOGGEDOUT but Opted---"; 
    }
```

Problem is :

**UPDATED:**

The below array key's for 0 and 1 index keeps changing, like sometimes [0]['action_key'] is loggedin and sometimes optin and also value may vary from 0 or 1.

So i am trying for all combinations in the conditions.

**Like example:**

> [0]['action_key']=loggedin and [0]['value']=0 and [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6n8s.png)['action_key']=optin and [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6n8s.png)['value']=0
>
> [0]['action_key']=optin and [0]['value']=0 and and [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6n8s.png)['action_key']=loggedin and [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6n8s.png)['value']=1
>
> [0]['action_key']=loggedin and [0]['value']=1 ...

and all possible combinations.

for which i am using like:

```
    if( ($userInfoArray[0]['action_key'] =='loggedin' && $userInfoArray[0]['value']==1) && ($userInfoArray[1]['action_key'] =='optin' && $userInfoArray[1]['value'] ==0 )   )
    {}

    else if( ($userInfoArray[0]['action_key'] =='optin' && $userInfoArray[0]['value']==0) && ($userInfoArray[1]['action_key'] =='loggedin' && $userInfoArray[1]['value'] ==1 )   )
    {}
```

If i try above code like i have used, code doesnt goes too long.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the given code?

Comment: Have updated the problem with the snippet @NicoHaase

Comment: @Sushivam Without the 'and' and the 'but' variations, perhaps this is an option https://3v4l.org/ZsKML

Comment: Have updated the question @Thefourthbird.. my condition should check the 2 index's array keys and values together in one if condition..ie) both [0]'s key and value and [1]'s key and value in single if statement and check for all combinations

Comment: @Sushivam I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to do other things than just printing messages, I suggest using a switch on selected elements of the sorted input array.

```
sort($userInfoArray);
switch (array_column($userInfoArray, 'value', 'action_key')) {
    case ['loggedin' => 1, 'optin' => 1]:
        echo "LOGGEDIN and OPTIN---";
    break;

    case ['loggedin' => 0, 'optin' => 0]:
        echo "LOGOUT and OPTOUT---";
    break;

    case ['loggedin' => 1, 'optin' => 0]:
        echo "LOGGEDIN and Not Opted---"; 
    break;

    case ['loggedin' => 0, 'optin' => 1]:
        echo "LOGGEDOUT but Opted---";
    break;
}
```

This way, `optin` can be first and `loggedin` second and it would still match correctly.

```
$userInfoArray = [
    [
        'action_key' => 'optin',
        'value' => 0,
    ],
    [
        'action_key' => 'loggedin',
        'value' => 1,
    ],
];
```

Output:

```
LOGGEDIN and Not Opted---
```

See https://3v4l.org/8Yqfa

Comment: This seems to work fine now...! thanks for the suggestion.. Have accepted answer @Rei

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to avoid if statements and define our conditions and messages in some other array. In order to do it we should:

1. Map our input array to the form `actionkey => actionvalue`, for
   example: `"loggedin" => 0`
2. Specify in array our conditions and messages that should be printed if the conditions are met
3. Filter out those messages which conditions are not ok with our input values
4. Print messages that are left

Sample code:

```
<?php

$input = [
    [
        'actionkey' => 'loggedin',
        'value' => 1
    ],
    [
        'actionkey' => 'optin',
        'value' => 0
    ]
];

//let's map it into actionkey => value
$actionValue = array_reduce(
    $input,
    function (array $out, $item) {
        $out[$item['actionkey']] = $item['value'];
        return $out;
    },
    []
);

$flow = [
    [
        "when" => [ "loggedin" => 1, "optin" => 1 ],
        "then" => "LOGGEDIN and OPTIN---"
    ],
    [
        "when" => [ "loggedin" => 0, "optin" => 0 ],
        "then" => "LOGOUT and OPTOUT---"
    ],
    [
        "when" => [ "loggedin" => 1, "optin" => 0 ],
        "then" => "LOGGEDIN and Not Opted---"
    ],
    [
        "when" => [ "loggedin" => 0, "optin" => 1 ],
        "then" => "LOGGEDOUT but Opted---"
    ],
];

$messagesToPrint =
    array_column(
        array_filter(
            $flow,
            function (array $item) use ($actionValue) {
                return empty(array_diff_assoc($item['when'], $actionValue));
            }
        ),
        "then"
    );

echo implode("\n", $messagesToPrint);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all possibilities and the keys can change between 0 and 1, you could use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and use `action_key` as the second paramter to make that value the key instead of the 0 or 1.

As an example without the `and` and `but` variations:

```
$userInfoArray = array(
    0 => array(
        'action_key' => 'loggedin',
        'value' => 1
    ),
    1 => array(
        'action_key' => 'optin',
        'value' => 0
    )
);

$message = "";
$actionKeyToKey = array_column($userInfoArray, null, 'action_key');
$message .= $actionKeyToKey['loggedin']['value'] ? 'LOGGEDIN' : 'LOGOUT';
$message .= $actionKeyToKey['optin']['value'] ? ' OPTIN---' : ' Not Opted---';
echo $message;
```

That way you can construct your message.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/RMf3g)

Answer (score 0):

I can't assure for this is correct code. But i think below code will give you idea to solve your problem

```
<?php 

        $array = array(

            0 => array(
                'actionkey' => 'loggedin',
                'value' => 1
            ),
            1 => array(
                'actionkey' => 'optin',
                'value' => 0
            )
        );

        foreach ($array as $key => $value){

            foreach ($value as $keyy => $data) {
                echo $keyy; 
                echo "<br>";
            }
            echo "<br>"; 
        }
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the output? How does it manage to print "Not loggedin and opted"?

Comment: Happy to hear that